# std::regex and ignoring flags

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

After learning basic [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) rules,I specialized my focus on `std::regex`, creating two console apps: 1.`renrem` and 2.`bfind`.
And I decided to create some convenient functions to deal with `regex` in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) as easy as possible plus all with `std`; named RFC ( = regex function collection )

There are several strange things that always make me surprise, but this one ruined all my attempt and those two console apps.

One of the important functions is `count_match` that counts number of match inside a string.  Here is the full code:

```
unsigned int count_match( const std::string& user_string, const std::string& user_pattern, const std::string& flags = "o" ){

    const bool flags_has_i = flags.find( "i" ) < flags.size();
    const bool flags_has_g = flags.find( "g" ) < flags.size();

    std::regex::flag_type regex_flag                  = flags_has_i ? std::regex_constants::icase         : std::regex_constants::ECMAScript;
//    std::regex_constants::match_flag_type search_flag = flags_has_g ? std::regex_constants::match_default : std::regex_constants::format_first_only;
    std::regex rx( user_pattern, regex_flag );
    std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

    unsigned int counter = 0;
    std::string temp = user_string;
    while( std::regex_search( temp, mr, rx ) ){
        temp = mr.suffix().str();
        ++counter;
    }

    if( flags_has_g ){
        return counter;
    } else {
        if( counter >= 1 ) return 1;
        else               return 0;
    }

}
```

First of all, as you can see, the line for `search_flag` was commented because it is ignored by `std::regex_search` and **I do not know why?** since -- the exact flag is accepted for `std::regex_repalce`. So `std::regex_search` ignores the `format_first_only` but `std::regex_replace` accepts it. Let's it goes.

The main problem is here that the `icase` flag is also ignored when the pattern is **character class** -> `[]`. In fact when the pattern is only `capital letter` or `small letter`: `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`

Supposing this string s = `"ONE TWO THREE four five six seven"`

the output for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) `std`

```
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+" ) << '\n';          // 1 => First match
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "g" ) << '\n';     // 3 => Global match
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "gi" ) << '\n';    // 3 => Global match plus insensitive
```

whereas for the exact [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [d](/questions/tagged/d) laugauge and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) with `boost` the output is:

```
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+" ) << '\n';          // 1 => First match
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "g" ) << '\n';     // 3 => Global match
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "gi" ) << '\n';    // 7 => Global match plus insensitive
```

---

I know about regex flavors **PCRE**; or **ECMAScript 262** that c++ uses it, But I have no ides **why a simple flag, is ignored for the only search function that c++ has?**  Since `std::regex_iterator` and `std::regex_token_iterator` are also use this function internally.

And shortly, I can not use those two my apps and RFC with `std` library because if this!

So if someone knows according to which rule it is maybe a valid rude in `ECMAScript 262` or perhaps if I am wrong anywhere please tell me.  Thanks.

---

*tested with*

```
gcc version 6.3.0 20170519 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04)
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4
```

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) code:

```
perl -le '++$c while $ARGV[0] =~ m/[A-Z]+/g; print $c ;' "ONE TWO THREE four five six seven" // 3
perl -le '++$c while $ARGV[0] =~ m/[A-Z]+/gi; print $c ;' "ONE TWO THREE four five six seven" // 7
```

[d](/questions/tagged/d) code:

```
uint count_match( ref const (char[]) user_string, const (char[]) user_pattern, const (char[]) flags ){

    const bool flag_has_g = flags.indexOf( "g" ) != -1;

    Regex!( char ) rx = regex( user_pattern, flags );
    uint counter = 0;
    foreach( mr; matchAll( user_string, rx ) ){
        ++counter;
    }

    if( flag_has_g ){
        return counter;
    } else {
        if( counter >= 1 ) return 1;
        else               return 0;
    }
}
```

the output:

```
writeln( count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "g" ) );  // 3
writeln( count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "gi" ) ); // 7
```

[js](/questions/tagged/js) code:

```js
var s = "ONE TWO THREE four five six seven";

var rx1 = new RegExp( "[A-Z]+" , "g" );
var rx2 = new RegExp( "[A-Z]+" , "gi" );

var counter = 0;
while( rx1.exec( s ) ){
   ++counter;
}
document.write( counter + "<br>" ); // 3

counter = 0;
while( rx2.exec( s ) ){
   ++counter;
}
document.write( counter ); // 7
```

---

Okay. After testing with `gcc 7.1.0` it turned out that with version below `6.3.0` the output is: `1 3 3` and but with `7.1.0` the output is `1 3 7`
[here is the link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5RZpHZJGJfB1FHnE).

Also with this version of `clang` the output is correct. [Here is the link](http://rextester.com/OEWX18211). thanks to **igor-tandetnik** user

Comment: I think I have already seen a question related to the fact the case insensitive flag does not work for character classes in `std::regex`, unfortunately, with no answer. I think it is just a bug.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Hi Wiktor. Well, bug in the library or in the compiler. If in the library why does it exist after 5 years?

Comment: No idea. A [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026965) does not help understand that either. I do not know if choosing another flavor (other than `ECMAScript`) helps. Have you tried them all?

Comment: have you tried calling std::regex_traits::translate_nocase directly to see what the output is?  Maybe you have a strange locale set somehow?   That is the function used under the covers when icase is set:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript  Grasping at straws... or maybe try it with the `collate` option set?

Comment: No. But I can. and before that, that is a long page, which section should I read?

Comment: @k-five i just text searched for icase and read those parts.. .but I don't know if it helped at all. :-\

Comment: @xaxxon. As long as I understood, it says ** when the case becomes local sensitive that `std::regex_constants::collate` have been set. I do not think that is because of local sensitive. Thank you anyway

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. This question is about `regex_replace` that `icase` works with it.  And what do you mean for **Have you tried them all**. Do you mean if I tested that code with `boost` and `D` and `Perl`. if so, **yes**  I am familiar with `perl` and `D` too. But I think may it is a `ECMA` rule. Since the pattern `\\w+` works well.

Comment: Your example [works for me](http://rextester.com/OEWX18211), prints `1 3 7`

Comment: @igor-tandetnik. Which version of `clang` the version `3.8` prints `1 3 3` for me

Comment: Clang 3.8.0, if the comment at the top is to be believed. Also [works with MSVC](http://rextester.com/MBOLY88533). Does *not* [work with gcc 5.4](http://rextester.com/FADE17660); I suspect a buggy standard library implementation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik. Thank you. I did not think this was a bug in the gcc. I was mostly suspicious for `regex` library.

Comment: @k-five `std::regex` supports [6 regex flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I already tested all of them `awk` and `egrep` and son on. None of them worked. I am regret for spending my time on this buggy and strange and confusing library. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I thought may this is a rule for `ECMAScript`, but after testing [js](/questions/tagged/js) code and seeing **Igor Tandetnik** commend I test the code with `gcc 7.1.0` and it outputs the correct result.

For test the regex library, I use:

```
std::cout << ( rx.flags() & std::regex_constants::icase == std::regex_constants::icase ? "yes" : "no" ) << '\n';
```

So when the `icase` is set it returns `true` otherwise returns `false`. So I think there is no library fault.
[Here is the test with gcc 7.1.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5RZpHZJGJfB1FHnE)
Therefore all versions below `gcc 7.1.0` has incorrect output.

For `clang` I have no ideas since I have `clang 3.8.0` and it has incorrect output. But the online version even `3.7.1` output is correct.

screenshot with `clang 3.8.0` for this code:

```
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+" ) << '\n';          // 1 => First match
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "g" ) << '\n';     // 3 => Global match
std::cout << count_match( s, "[A-Z]+", "gi" ) << '\n';    // 7 => Global match plus insensitive
```

[image]

So with online compiler [the output is incorrect for clang `3.2` and below](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tm8H70x6vMQHd4RU). But higher version outputs the correct result.

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, as you can see, the line for search_flag was commented because it is ignored by std::regex_search and I do not know why? since -- the exact flag is accepted for std::regex_repalce.

The flag in question is `format_first_only`. This flag makes sense *only* for a "replace" operation. In `regex_replace`, the default is "replace all" but if you pass this flag it becomes "replace first only."

In `regex_match` and `regex_search`, there is no replacement going on at all; both of those functions just find the first match (and in the case of `regex_match`, that match *must* consume the entire string). Since the flag is meaningless in that case, I would expect the implementation to ignore it; but I wouldn't fault the implementation for throwing an exception, either, if it chose to be noisy about it.

---

> The main problem is here that the icase flag is also ignored when the pattern is character class -> []. In fact when the pattern is only capital letter or small letter: [A-Z] or [a-z]

`icase` working wrong for character classes is definitely a bug in your vendor's library.

- [Looks like](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SGJnT4WUH55UifXQ) libstdc++'s bug was fixed between GCC 6.3 (Dec 2016) and GCC 7.1 (May 2017).
- [Looks like](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SGJnT4WUH55UifXQ) libc++'s bug was fixed between Clang 3.2 (Dec 2012) and Clang 3.3 (Jun 2013).