# Regex search for Text then match elements

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

I would like to install a condition. I have already tried a lot but without success. Would someone be so kind and would help me?

My goal: if SharedKeys true then match elements(A B C D).

> SharedKeys = "A","B","C","D"

Regex:  `(?!\")[A-Z]*?(?=\")`

Match elements: A B C D

Update: `(SharedKeys)?(?(1)|(?!\")[A-Z]*?(?=\"))`

Match elements: SharedKeys A B C D

Link: https://regex101.com/r/WFxZh4/1

I think i have now what i needed, maybe helps others.

> SharedKeys = "A","B","C","D"
>
> BlaBla = "B", "B", "C"

Result: `(SharedKeys|BlaBla)?(?(1)|(?!\")[A-Z]*?(?=\"))`

Match elements: SharedKeys A B C D BlaBla B B C

Result for c++: `[A-Za-z]+|(?!\")[A-Z]*?(?=\")` (std::regex)

Comment: What do you mean with **SharedKeys**

Comment: some times it's easier to match 'Sendkeys = ....' and then match elements inside the recent matched string, in two steps @Lendoria

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you do little example?

Comment: read [C++: what regex library should I use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use) and [Comparison of regular expression engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines)

Comment: you are looking for `c++` code or **c++ pattern**?

Comment: `C++` does not support **if else** condition. So your pattern is fail. It support by default: `ECMAScript 262`

Comment: Instead of `std:::regex` that is buggy and poor, you can use: `boost::regex`

Comment: I added `c++` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `std::regex`:

```
std::string s1( R"(SharedKeys = "A","B","C","D")" );
std::regex rx( "(SharedKeys)?(?(1)|[A-Z](?=\\\"))" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

while( std::regex_search( s1, mr, rx ) ){
    std::cout << mr.str() << '\n';
    s1 = mr.suffix().str();
}
```

the output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'  
what():  Invalid special open parenthesis. Aborted (core dumped)
```

with `boost::regex`:

```
std::string s1( R"(SharedKeys = "A","B","C","D")" );
boost::regex rx( "(SharedKeys)?(?(1)|[A-Z](?=\\\"))" );
boost::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

while( boost::regex_search( s1, mr, rx ) ){
    std::cout << mr.str() << '\n';
    s1 = mr.suffix().str();
}
```

the output:

```
SharedKeys
A
B
C
D
```

---

here you can see the difference between this two flavors:

[image: boost_regex_table]

[source of the screenshot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/boost.html)

---

Note. The `std::regex` is buggy especially with [gcc version `6.3.0` and lower versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735201/stdregex-and-ignoring-flags/44739179#44739179)

Comment: Thanks for your description! I use only std:regex so i have write another algorythm. In futur maybe i add Boost:regex. Thank you!

Comment: @Lendoria. you are welcome. It  is faster and richer and safer