# C++ regex bug! Square bracket expression does not work with icase flag

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

```
// regex_replace example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::string INPUT = "Replace_All_Characters_With_Anything";
  std::string OUTEXP = "0";
  std::regex expression("[A-Za-z]", std::regex_constants::icase);
  std::cout << std::regex_replace(INPUT, expression, OUTEXP);

  return 0;
}
```

This works here: http://cpp.sh/6gb5a
This works here: https://regexr.com/5bt9d

The problem seems to be down to using icase flag or not. A in All, the C in Characters, the W in With, etc. does not get replaced because of the underscore existing. The bug seems to be that using `[]` to match things only works if said character does not come after a non match.

There does seem to be a quick fix for this, if brackets are followed by a {1}, then it works.

example: `[A-Za-z]{1}`

Compiler:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 / Version 16.7.3 / c++17

Also tested in c++14, same bad behavior

expected result:
[image]

my result:
[image]

Comment: What exact compiler you are using? Works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95b9b40292545b2a) as well.

Comment: *It doesn't work in my c++ environment*  --  What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?.

Comment: It doesn't work as explained by the post. "The problem is that the A in All, the C in Characters, the W in With, etc. does not get replaced because of the underscore existing. The bug seems to be that using [] to match things only works if said character does not come after a non match."

Comment: Works with VC++ 2019, 16.7.1.  You should always check if the latest version has fixed issues.

Comment: When you install Visual Studio, there is a Visual Studio updater application.  As a matter of fact, you should have gotten messages when starting Visual Studio IDE letting you know there are new versions of Visual Studio available.  You use the updater application to install the latest version.

Comment: I just added an image that demonstrates that the regex is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Have you tried replacing those upper-case characters with lower case to see if that's part of the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the "A" in "All" is the letter `A` (ASCII-65) and not some unicode alternative that has a glyph similar to "A".

Comment: @ElanHickler Cannot duplicate the bug with VS 2019 16.7.3 in either of the C++17 debug/release x86/x64 combinations.

Comment: @MartinYork you might be on to something, I just did another test using raw string and it worked as expected.

Comment: What the hell, so it looks like if I remove the icase flag in my code, it works. In other words, having the icase flag causes it not to work. But then... the icase flag in another compiler still works as expected.

Comment: @dxiv and @PaulMcKenzie please retest using icase `std::regex("[A-Za-z]", std::regex_constants::icase)`

Comment: @ElanHickler Confirmed with `icase`. Sounds reminiscent of this old [::std::regex_replace with syntax flag icase on Windows (VS2013 Update 4, VS2015 Update 3) does not match using character ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026965/stdregex-replace-with-syntax-flag-icase-on-windows-vs2013-update-4-vs2015).

Comment: Looks like a bug, reproduces on rextester https://rextester.com/live/DJAQ2285

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is an appropriate use of answering. But this is a known bug and it looks like the bug has been known for a few months. No ETA on a fix as far as I can see.

https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/993

Looks like RE2 is a recommended alternative regex library.

https://github.com/google/re2/

Instead of using another library, I will create a function that can be used to intercept and change the regex expression string as a temporary fix. Should work whether or not icase flag is used.

test code: https://rextester.com/LSNW3495

```cpp
// add '{1}' after square bracket ranges unless there already is a quantifier or alternation such as '?' '*' '+' '{}' 
std::string temporaryBugFix(std::string exp)
{
    enum State
    {
        start,
        skipNext,
        lookForEndBracket,
        foundEndBracket,
    };

    State state = start;
    State prevState = start;

    int p = -1;
    std::vector<int> positionsToFix;

    for (auto c : exp)
    {
        ++p;

        switch (state)
        {
        case start:
            if (c == '\\')
            {
                prevState = state;
                state = skipNext;
            }
            else if (c == '[')
                state = lookForEndBracket;

            continue;

        case skipNext:
            state = prevState;
            continue;

        case lookForEndBracket:
            if (c == '\\')
            {
                prevState = state;
                state = skipNext;
            }
            else if (c == ']')
            {
                state = foundEndBracket;
                if (p + 1 == exp.length())
                    positionsToFix.push_back(p + 1);
            }
            continue;

        case foundEndBracket:
            if (c != '+' && c != '*' && c != '?')
                positionsToFix.push_back(p);
            state = start;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // check for valid curly brackets so we don't add an additional one
    std::string s = exp;
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex e("\\{\\d+,?\\d*?\\}");

    int offset = 0;
    vector<int> validCurlyBracketPositions;
    while (regex_search(s, m, e))
    {
        validCurlyBracketPositions.push_back(m.position(0) + offset);
        offset += m.position(0) + m[0].length();
        s = m.suffix();
    }

    // remove valid curly bracket positions from the fix vector
    for (auto p : validCurlyBracketPositions)
        positionsToFix.erase(std::remove(positionsToFix.begin(), positionsToFix.end(), p), positionsToFix.end());

    // insert the fixes
    for (int i = positionsToFix.size(); i--; )
        exp.insert(positionsToFix[i], "{1}");

    return exp;
}
```